# Java application accessing multiple versions of a library

Tags: java, annotations, version

I am writing a client (Eclipse RCP) that needs to be able to use multiple versions of a library (which encapsulates the backend interface). Each version of the library adds some new classes/methods that are used by the client. In case an older lib version is used, the client will access new classes/methods that are not present in the lib bytecode, resulting in NoClassDefFoundError.

So I am thinking of how to do this the best way. The most simple way to make it fail-safe is to wrap all calls to such code into try/catch blocks I guess. I was thinking of writing a custom annotation for marking new code in the library source, and then issue a compiler warning when such marked code is accessed from code that is not secured by try/catch (can this be done by a custom annotation? Haven't written one before). Or can someone think of a different approach that is more elegant?

Answer (score -1):

You can use maven repository for providing different version of your library. 
Maven central repository is available for releases:
http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-central-repository-upload.html

You can setup own instance of Artifactory: http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Configuring+Maven+Deployment+to+Artifactory

Comment: This is not at all what I am asking for. The issue is not about how to get the lib versions, but how to handle the stuff I am talking about in the code.

Comment: Good way is interfaces. 
You can provide interfaces that will use clients. New implementation will be provided for user without issues.